# Variables within ADSI command on remote PowerShell target

Tags: powershell, adsi

I'm automating changing passwords on remote PowerShell targets using an ADSI command I send through `Invoke-Command`. I'm using the following PowerShell command to send the ADSI command to the remote machine:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
  (([ADSI]“WinNT://localhost/Administrator”).SetPassword($new_password)).SetInfo
} -Credential $mycred
```

Everything works except for the `$new_password` variable. If I enter a string directly in the ADSI command (in the `SetPassword()` method), the password is changed successfully on the remote client. However if I use the `$new_password` variable instead, then the administrator password on the remote client gets set as blank. All other variables, i.e `$computer` and `$mycred` seem to work properly in the entire `Invoke-Command` command, however it's only that one $new_password that isn't working. Even if I do the following:

```
$new_password = "mypassword"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
  (([ADSI]“WinNT://localhost/Administrator”).SetPassword($new_password)).SetInfo
} -Credential $mycred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

passing variables into scriptblock should be like this :

```
$new_password = "mypassword"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer  -Credential $mycred -ScriptBlock {param($new_password) (([ADSI]“WinNT://localhost/Administrator,user”).SetPassword($new_password)).SetInfo } -argumentlist $new_password
```

and the adsi should be `([ADSI]“WinNT://localhost/Administrator,user”)`